# Block file from accessing using .htaccess for a subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, block

I have a website for e.g.

```
www.domain.com
```

And I have another subdomain for e.g.

```
test.domain.com
```

Both my main and subdomain point to same directory which is **public_html**.

I want to block access to

```
test.domain.com/test.jpg
```

but not

```
domain.com/test.jpg
```

Please note that this **test.jpg** is same file for both main and subdomain as they both point to same directory. So how do I block it for subdomain but not for main domain using .htaccess? Or is there any other way of doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An .htaccess file will be used regardless of the virtual host (unless explicitly deactivated using AllowOverride None), therefore you'll have to put:

```
<Files /full/path/to/test.jpg>
  Deny From All
</Files>
```

in the apache configuration file inside the `test.domain.com` virtual host configuration.

Comment: Ok where is that virtual host config file normally found? And what will be its name like apache.config e.t.c!?

Comment: I did like you said in apache config file inside the subdomain but it is not working. I wrote complete file path as "/home/myusr/public_html/test.jpg". I have even restarted apache but no luck.

Comment: you should add the edited virtual host configuration to your question so we can try to troubleshoot it :)

Comment: Found answer here using .htaccess http://serverfault.com/questions/236144/block-file-from-accessing-using-htaccess-for-a-subdomain